# Django while deleting entry getting error local variable 'delete' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Can someone explain and correct me on deleting entries?

```
 url(r'^remove/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'registration.views.removerequest'),


 <a href = '/remove/{{ object.id }}/'>remove</a>

 #view

def removerequest(request,id):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated(): 
        get_objects=Todos.objects.get(pk=id)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/remove/')
    if request.method =='POST':
        delete= get_objects.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    context = {'delete':delete}
    return render_to_response('remove.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: This isn't a question about deleting objects. You have so many logic errors in that code I don't even know where to start. Why is `get_objects` defined if the user is not authenticated, but then you return immediately? In the POST block, where is that `get_objects` supposed to be coming from? What are you expecting as the return value of `delete()`? Where is `delete` coming from if it's not a POST? Please think logically about your code before posting, and indeed before programming.

Comment: I am very new to programming and django however I understand what you mean. Basically I am trying to delete entry and before deleting it should ask if i am sure to continue deleting. But i understand what you mean this is logically incorrect what i am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed as good as i could...as [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) said...there are tooo many logic errors.

**template**

```
<a href = '/remove/{{ object_to_delete.id }}/'>remove</a>
```

**view**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required #only allow deletion for authenticated users
def removerequest(request,id):
    get_objects=Todos.objects.get(pk=id) #get the todo object

    if request.method =='POST': # if form is submitted
        delete= get_objects.delete() # delete the shit
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/') # return to profile URL
    # else
    context = {'object_to_delete': get_objects} # pass the todo object to the context
    return render_to_response('remove.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request)) #return all
```